# How do I ensure that a full screen Iframe is responsive on a mobile device?

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I am trying to display full webpages on my website using an Iframe, code here:

```
<iframe name="demo" src="http://healthcoach.ancorathemes.com/"; style='height: 100%; 
width: 100%;' frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" id="iframe">...</iframe>
```

This works fine on a desktop browser but on a mobile device, won't resize and still shows the desktop version. This particular website is responsive by the way and works fine without an Iframe.

Comment: when your iframe has a fixed format: https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php if not, try this https://npr.github.io/responsiveiframe/

Answer (score -1):

For **iframe** to be responsive just change the width defined in pixels to percentage for eg:

```
height: 100%; 
width: 100%;
```

Comment: yes you have done that. And it had worked. your site is responsive.